# How to transfer data from one list to another and then update it automatically

Tags: sharepoint-designer, copy, copy-content

Just a little background on how the problem originated - we've been running a bunch of tables on local drives and decided to move them to sharepoint in order to work with those tables simultaniously and automate the the filling of tables somehow. So now we have a bunch of tables transfered to lists, and already started filling them in. The management decided to use PowerBI to build dashboards based on those new lists by directly uploading from Sharepoint, but it turned out to be problem since the lists contained AdvancedLookUp columns and PowerBi cannot read them (even through oData).
So now to my problem - I decided to try to create a copy of all those lists (shadow copy) so it would be first fully copied and then updated aotumatically upon new entries in original table.
So for example we have List1 with columns 1 2 3 and a bunch of elements already created in this list. 
1) First I want to copy all the existing data from List1 to ListCopy1. 
2) Secondly after there is an element created in List1 it would create the same element with all columns filled from List 1 in ListCopy1. It would be even better if the data copied would be in plain text for easier management in PowerBI.

I'm using Sharepoint 2013 and have access to SharepointDesigner 2013, but my knowledge in running SD2013 is really low, so please go in a bit more details in explanation if possible.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options for this.
1. Workflow ( add to other list when item created & update item when it has been changed )
2. Event Recevier